# duplication of images in the report

Tags: fonts, graphics, sectioning

when creating a report I want to create a "frame" in which I put the photo, everything works fine, but I have to do it twice (sc1 and sc2 treat the same), but latex "reads" it as the same even though it gives two different images, how can I fix this to treat sc1 and sc2 as two different images

my code:

```
Note: here should be just sc1\\
\newcommand\cropped[1]{%
    \immediate\write18{convert -trim #1.png #1cropped.png}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{listings/sc1.png}}
\fbox{\cropped{image}}

Note: here should be just sc2\\
\newcommand\cropped[1]{%
    \immediate\write18{convert -trim #1.png #1cropped.png}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{listings/sc2.png}}
\fbox{\cropped{image}}
```

as you can see I want to do it to show sc1 and sc2, but the pictures are duplicated, it shows sc1 twice.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem here is that you define the same macro twice. If you want to redefine a macro that you previously already defined, you need to use `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand` for the redefinition. Otherwise the first definition will be used again and an error will be issed.

However, macros are typically defined to make things easier, especially if you want to do the same thing over and over again. So, it may be more reasonable to define your macro once  (preferably in your preamble) and then just use it twice.

So, you could, for example use the following setup (although it is not fully clear to me why you want to crop a PNG file but then use another image in your TeX file):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\cropped[2]{%
    \immediate\write18{convert -trim #1.png #1cropped.png}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}}

\begin{document}

Note: here should be just sc1\\
\fbox{\cropped{image}{listings/sc1.png}}

Note: here should be just sc2\\
\fbox{\cropped{image}{listings/sc2.png}}
    
\end{document}
```